# Git push from Delphi IDE

Tags: git, delphi

Trying to commit and push to GIT repository from Delphi 11. Commit works fine, but push shows error `Invalid URL: "git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxxx/projectname.git"`. URL itself is fine. Why I'm getting this error and how to solve the problem?

I do `git->Push->From Repository Root`

Pushing from terminal works fine.

[image]

Error details:

```
[7B892869]{rtl280.bpl  } System.Net.URLClient.TURI.ComposeURI (Line 1088, "System.Net.URLClient.pas" + 6) + $F
[7B892053]{rtl280.bpl  } System.Net.URLClient..{System.Generics.Collections}TDictionary<System.string,System.Net.URLClient.TURLStream.TSyncReqExecutor> (Line 622, "System.Net.URLClient.pas" + 0) + $AC27
[26A3FA9A]{gitide280.bpl} GitClient.TGitClient.EnsureUserAuthentication (Line 1544, "GitClient.pas" + 7) + $6
[26A406E9]{gitide280.bpl} GitClient.TGitClient.Push (Line 1731, "GitClient.pas" + 3) + $7
[26A89E16]{gitide280.bpl} GitIDEPush.DoPush (Line 139, "GitIDEPush.pas" + 7) + $E
[26A89CB3]{gitide280.bpl} GitIDEPush.TBasePushGitMenu.Execute (Line 122, "GitIDEPush.pas" + 22) + $E
[7A927A96]{coreide280.bpl} ContainerIntf.TProjectManagerMenuItem.Click (Line 1110, "ContainerIntf.pas" + 18) + $22
[7A555C5B]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Menus.TMenu.DispatchCommand (Line 3576, "Vcl.Menus.pas" + 5) + $2
[7A556ED6]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Menus.TPopupList.WndProc (Line 4749, "Vcl.Menus.pas" + 4) + $E
[7B5A0AB4]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TMonitor.CheckOwningThread (Line 19889, "System.pas" + 2) + $0
[7B5A0DDA]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 20079, "System.pas" + 1) + $2
[7B5A0E36]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 20101, "System.pas" + 2) + $7
[7A40821D]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Graphics.FreeMemoryContexts (Line 7308, "Vcl.Graphics.pas" + 12) + $8
[7A42C700]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 10321, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[7A556E25]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Menus.TPopupList.MainWndProc (Line 4724, "Vcl.Menus.pas" + 2) + $5
[7B6B5C1C]{rtl280.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 18517, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[7A575263]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 11488, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[7A5752A6]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 11518, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[7A5755E5]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 11657, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 27) + $3
[006D80A2]{bds.exe     } bds.bds (Line 227, "" + 16) + $2
```

Comment: does it work pushing from terminal?

Comment: Could you try to push to different URLs like `git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxxx/project1.git`, `git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxxx/project2.git`? Does the error persist? Try to change the URL to `ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxxxxxx/projectname.git` format.

Comment: Callstack suggests that IDE uses https protocol and not SSH.

Comment: I agree with @DalijaPrasnikar's comment : the stack suggests your setting is handled as an https uri

Comment: @phd not a big deal but I don't think that's the case. OP states that they are trying _from Delphi_.

Comment: OK.... I see _why_ I missed it. I had assumed that whatever was following "I do `git->Push->From Repository Root`" was output from the operation.... _now_ I see it. :-D